# Setting Date Value in Controller of Spring Boot Application (Java 8)

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, gradle, java-8

In my model I have the following:

```
private Date exampleDate;

public Testing(Date exampleDate) {
        this.exampleDate = exampleDate;
    }

public Date getExampleDate() {
        return (Date) this.exampleDate.clone();
    }

    public void setExampleDate(Date exampleDate) {
        this.exampleDate = (Date) exampleDate.clone();
    }
```

And I am trying to output an array of objects as follows

```
@RestController
public class TestingController {
    @GetMapping("/saved")
    public List<Testing> getData() {
        List<Testing> savedDatas = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                new Testing(
                        1,
                        "Text",
                        2000-1- 1),
                new Testing(
                        2,
                        "Text2",
                        new Date(27 / 03 / 19)),
```

I tried to use new Date but that doesn't work, so what exactly do I need to pass as the third argument as type `Date` instead of String or int?!?!

Comment: What package does `Date` come from? Is it `java.util.Date`?

Comment: @Nikolas yes...

Comment: When you use Java 8 then **PLEASE don't use the 20 year old *deprecated* `java.util.Date`**. Use `java.time.LocalDate` instead

Comment: Your Question is not clear. plz share what exception do you get?

Comment: Consider using `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` instead as of [tag:java-8].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use the newer classes:

```
LocalDateTime
```

and

```
ZonedDateTime
```

Then you can get a LocalDateTime instance by using the static factory methods:

```
LocalDateTime.of(date, time); //or
LocalDate.of(date);
```